# Ract Native App stuck on splash screen on device but works in simulator

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I've deployed a react native app on play store (using expo) the app works fine on simulator (Android simulator) but when I install it into my android phone from play store it'll be stuck on splash screen.
I've tried multiple solutions available sadly non of them worked.
-This is my App.js :

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useFonts } from '@expo-google-fonts/inter';
import RootNav from "./src/Routes/RootNav";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'caviar-dreams-bold': require('./assets/fonts/CaviarDreams_Bold.ttf'),
    'caviar-dreams-bold-italic': require('./assets/fonts/CaviarDreams_BoldItalic.ttf'),
    'caviar-dreams-italic': require('./assets/fonts/CaviarDreams_Italic.ttf'),
    'caviar-dreams': require('./assets/fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf'),
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        if(!fontsLoaded){
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useEffect(() => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      console.log(appIsReady);
       SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <RootNav onLayout={onLayoutRootView}/>
  );
}
```

- Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "aselpay",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-community-flipper": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.17.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.175.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "zustand": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

- I've used `expo start --no-dev --minify` the app works fine. I have no errors no warnings.
- I used to have animation, I totally removed them, and it didn't help.

Comment: If it works on the sim but not a device, then it may be api signing key issue.

Comment: @MikeS. Could you please explain more!

Comment: For Google, make sure you have all the API production keys in a config file for android. I don't remember offhand the names. Also ensure that the app being uploaded is the production version.